# some node_modules is not pushing in git after having locally in angular

Tags: angular, git

Some of node_modules is locally present when i forket repository its not working due to module not present error.

Here is screenshot. 
[image]

Some of files was missing inside node_modules while cloning repository on different machine or different folder locally also.

sometime i have to copy paste missing node_modules files then its works.

is there something wrong with gitignore or node_modules ?

Comment: You dont really want your node_modules folder in your git because it takes a lot of space. 
In your package.json all the packages are refferenced. When you run 'npm install' or 'yarn install'. The packages from the package.json will be downloaded in the node_modules folder.

Comment: i already push. I dont want to remove now. so 1-2 node_modules missing files to commit in git. as per screenshot.  Everytime i need to copy paste that file and make it run

Comment: **Never push node_modules**. Period! They will always change based on your package configuration.

Comment: Its correct. I need to have answer on this question. If such scenarios is there how to solve. I did already push node_modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for this is to exlude particular node_modules library which is missing.

.gitignore

```
*.zip
.idea/
.vscode/
node_modules/.cache/
dist/ 
!node_modules/ngx-mydatepicker/dist/
```